# How to pass multiple parameters in magento rest api2

Tags: api, rest, magento

How to pass multiple parameters in magento rest api2 apart from default parameter which we'll mention in api2.xml

```
<routes>
        <route_collection>
            <route>/appointmentupdate/:appointmentid</route>
            <action_type>collection</action_type>
        </route_collection>
</routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found this inside another api2 magento call

```
app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\etc\api2.xml:
  187:                         <route>/products/:id/store/:store</route>
```

so url call will be:

> products/[id]/[store]

Answer (score 0):

**simply Add code for Multiple Parameter pass in your web.xml file**

**[vendorname]/[modulename]/etc**

***web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

<route url="/V1/products/getproductprice/:sku" method="GET">
    <service class="Evamp\Webapi\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getProductPrice"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

 <route url="/V1/products/getproductattribute/:sku/:attributecode" method="GET">
           <service class="Evamp\Webapi\Api\ProductsInterface" method="getProductAttribute"/>
            <resources>
              <resource ref="anonymous"/>
            </resources>
    </route>
```

now create an interface file in

**[vendorname]/[modulename]/Api**

***ProductsInterface.php***

```
    interface ProductsInterface
  {
    /**
   * Returns greeting message to user
   *
   * @api
 * @param string $sku
 * @return string Greeting message with users name.
 */
public function getProductPrice($sku);
/**
 * @param $sku
 * @param $attributecode
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getProductAttribute($sku, $attributecode);
}
```

now create an  file that implement this Abstract Method

**[vendorname]/[modulename]/Modal**

```
class Products implements ProductsInterface
{
/**
 * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
 */
private $_productRepository;
/**
 * Product constructor.
 * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 */
public function __construct(ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
/**
 * Returns greeting message to user
 *
 * @param string $sku
 * @return string Greeting message with users name.
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 * @api
 */
public function getProductPrice($sku)
{
    $prodcutBySku = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    return $prodcutBySku->getPrice();
}
/**
 * @param $sku
 * @param $attributecode
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeInterface|null
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getProductAttribute($sku, $attributecode)
{
    $prodcutBySku = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    return $prodcutBySku->getCustomAttribute($attributecode);
}
}
```

now create a di.xml file which provide an method call in interface file

**[vendorname]/[modulename]/etc**

***di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="[vendorname]\[modulename]\Api\ProductsInterface"
                type="[vendorname]\[modalname]\Model\getProductPrice" />


    <preference for="[vendorname]\[modulename]\Api\ProductsInterface"
                type="[vendorname]\[modalname]\Model\getProductAttribute" />

</config>
```

**Note: the parameter name Must be same in Abstract Method in Interface File and Must be same in Method Implement File.**

type this URL in browser

```
http://<hostname>/rest/V1/products/getproductprice/<SKU of PRoduct>

http://<hostname>/rest/V1/products/getproductattribute/<SKU of Product>/<Product attribute code >
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***